# Upper triangular matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it true that if $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $T$ is a linear map with upper triangular matrix with respect to $v_i$ that then $Tv_i \in span(v_1,\cdots,v_{i})$?

Comment: That's only true if the matrix is _strictly_ upper triangular, that is, upper triangular with zero diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$?

Comment: I'm not sure. If $T:V \to W$ and $v_i$ is a basis of $V$ then $Tv_i$ is a basis of $W$. Does it contain information about columns of $T$?

Comment: Do you know how to obtain the matrix for $T$ with respect to the basis?

Comment: The $Tv_i$ give me $n$ equations. From these I can compute the matrix of $T$.

Comment: I don't know what equations you are referring to. The $i^{\text{th}}$ column consists of the coordinates of $T(v_i)$ with respect to the basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.

Comment: Now I understand. I made a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be true. Take $v_1 = (1,0),v_2 = (0,1)$ and $T$ as identity matrix. Than $Tv_1 \neq sv_2$ for any $s\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is why you need the matrix to be strictly upper triangular, as Daniel Fischer points out.

Comment: I made a typo in the question. It's corrected now.